# How to load WMS tiles only inside a bounding box in Leaflet?

Tags: leaflet, mapbox, tiles, wms

I have an application in which I use mapbox.js to load basemap tiles for a location. Then user can load WMS tiles from a WMS server, of size 256X256 which get loaded on top of the basemap.

I am using mapbox and leaflet to display map as follow:

```
 window.map = L.map('map', { 'minZoom': minZoomLevel(), 'maxZoom': maxZoomLevel(), reuseTiles: true, unloadInvisibleTiles: true }).setView(["35.7804", "-78.6391"], 17)
```

Then I am using Leaflet, to send requests to my server, and from there send request to WMS server to load tiles using this:

```
wms = L.tileLayer.wms('/viewers/wms', {
    minZoom: 12,
    maxZoom: 25,
    layers: 'some layer name',
    format: 'image/png',

    updateWhenIdle: false,
    transparent: true,

    reuseTiles: true,
    showTheRasterReturned: true,

    COVERAGE_CQL_FILTER: 'featureId=\'' + featureId + '\''
});
```

By the time the request reaches my server, a `BBOX` attribute is added automatically by leaflet which has different co-ordinates (I think it is taking full viewport) i.e.

```
 Started GET
 "/viewers/wms?SERVICE=WMS&REQUEST=GetMap&VERSION=1.1.1&LAYERS=some
 layer
 name&STYLES=&FORMAT=image%2Fpng&TRANSPARENT=true&HEIGHT=256&WIDTH=256&REUSETILES=true&SHOWTHERASTERRETURNED=true&COVERAGE_CQL_FILTER=featureId%3D%279d3a23cba90680cecda337a926f563a6%27&SRS=EPSG%3A3857&**BBOX=-8755402.967897227,4285977.050006404,-8755097.219784087,4286282.798119542**" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-06-27 16:51:01 -0400
```

A BBOX attribute is added by leaflet on the fly which are as follows

```
 BBOX=-8755402.967897227,4285977.050006404,-8755097.219784087,4286282.798119542"
```

although, I want to get tiles only for these co-ordinates:

```
southWest ={lat: 35.77712238348847, lng: -78.64827990531921} 
northEast {lat: 35.783693840245284, lng: -78.62991213798523}
```

setting up a `BBOX` option inside `L.tileLayer.wms` does not help either, as `BBOX` co-ordinates are added by leaflet.

Answer (score 2):

Leaflet is working as expected.

You just have to remember that while Leaflet uses different Coordinate Reference Systems (CRSs) for the display projection and for `L.LatLng`s. You specify `L.LatLng`s (and bounds, etc) in EPSG:4326 (AKA [equirectangular](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equirectangular_projection)), and Leaflet will translate everything into EPSG:3857 (AKA [Spherical Mercator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Mercator)).

Note how the URL for the WMS request includes a `SRS=EPSG%3A3857` parameter (which means `SRS=EPSG:3857` once [URI-decoded](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURIComponent)). This means that Leaflet is providing coordinates in EPSG:3857, and expecting an image projected in EPSG:3857.

If you see no images, that likely means that your WMS server does not support EPSG:3857. Also, I encourage you to read through the [Leaflet WMS/TMS tutorial](http://leafletjs.com/examples/wms/wms.html), which highlights how to use different CRSs with WMS raster sources.

> although, I want to get tiles only for these co-ordinates

Then use the [`bounds` option of `L.TileLayer.WMS`](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.3.0.html#gridlayer-bounds). (If you don't see this option in the documentation, remember that `L.TileLayer.WMS` inherits options from `L.TileLayer`, which in turn inherits options from `L.GridLayer`)

Like so:

```
wms = L.tileLayer.wms('/viewers/wms', {
 minZoom: 12,
 maxZoom: 25,
 layers: 'some layer name',
 format: 'image/png',
 updateWhenIdle: false,
 transparent: true,
 reuseTiles: true,
 showTheRasterReturned: true,
 COVERAGE_CQL_FILTER: 'featureId=\'' + featureId + '\''

 bounds: L.latLngBounds([[35.77, -78.65],[35.78, -78.63]])
});
```

Comment: Hi Ivan. Your example sets the layer bounds on creation. Do you know how I can set the bounds of an existing layer?